# Convert psql query into typeorm using query builder

Tags: node.js, database, typescript, psql, typeorm

I need to get data on daily/weekly/monthly basis. So i used date_trunc() and generate_series() to get this type of record. I made psql query but i need to convert it into typeorm code as i'm new to typeorm stack. Below is the query

```
SELECT sequential_dates.date, events.count
     FROM (select date_trunc('MONTH', months) AS date
     from generate_series('2021-05-03' :: DATE, '2021-05-31' :: DATE, '1 MONTH') as months ) sequential_dates
LEFT JOIN(
    select date_trunc('MONTH', events."createdAt") AS date, count(events.id)  as count
    from events where events."type" = 'LOGIN'
    group by date
) events
on sequential_dates.date = events.date
```

Comment: have you tried solving this yourself? you should show what you've tried out, or at least show that you have attempted to solve your question and you've researched possible solutions

Answer (score 0):

If it's not possible to express this using the TypeOrm API, then you can make raw queries:

```js
const rawData = await repository.query(`SELECT * FROM USERS`);
```

You'll have to handle the `rawData` manually (similar to https://typeorm.io/#/select-query-builder/getting-raw-results).

Docs: https://typeorm.io/#/repository-api. Search for "query - Executes a raw SQL query".